# expiresActive .htaccess error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I keep getting and external 500 error and I'm pretty sure it's to do with the htaccess file if anybody can see any issues .. . .please help. .

this is also coming up with the error if it helps

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at popertee.co.uk Port 443

```
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

       # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
       RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
       RewriteRule ^ - [L]


       RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
       RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
       RewriteRule . index.php [L]
       AllowOverride Indexes
       <FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.       (ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|woff)$">

       ExpiresActive On
       ExpiresDefault A2592000
       </FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the two rules rewriting to themselves

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
```

The problem is, in an .htaccess file the rules are run over and over again, until there is no more rewrite.

So, if you have a request for `test.php`, the second rule matches and rewrites to `test.php`. But then the rules are run a second time. Again, the second rule matches and is rewritten to `test.php`, and again and again.

Comment these lines and see, if the error goes away.

---

Since you suspect the `Expires*` directives, it might be, that you must enable the expires module first. This can be done by

```
a2enmod expires
```

and then reload or restart Apache.